# I have created a package of an App using nw.js. How can i create a dmg file to distribute it?

Tags: packaging, node-webkit

Actually there i have a html, CSS and java script based app and i created build of it using nw.js technology using build command. The problem is i want the application in dmg format. please help me finding way.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to package your app. You should read the documentation:

- https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Package%20and%20Distribute/

I do not know of any tutorials for creating an NW.js package as a DMG. Because the final dist is a single `.app` file, you could distribute that directly, or compressed in a Zip file or something similar. You may be able to look up instructions around DMG packaging that is not specific to NW.js and apply the concepts. If so, and you get it to work, you should write a blog post or tutorial about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/appdmg to create an installer for your NW App on macOS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

In my ongoing development for the same i found the making a .pkg installer is better than making .dmg with reasons you can search for.
so i found two solutions for the same.

1. packages(an application you can package anything with signed developer id)
2. buildPkg(a command line process to make package)
   in both you just need to add your application.app as mentioned in documentation and follow the steps.